# How to check for existing email in DB but excluding the one of a logged in customer?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

How to check if email is in database but excluding the email of a user which logged in?
I am using this code in my project when registering to check for email in database and it works fine...but I would like to give the option to update email for registered customer and thus exclude from counting his own email. When accessing Myprofile page (the one where customer can update his data) I am pulling all the info and writing it in text boxes so even when he updated his name only, all the rest is overwritten with same data. This is the code which works fine for all the emails:

```
 Function GetEmail() As Boolean
    Dim EmailOk As Boolean
    Dim CustomerId As Integer = 0

    Try
        If IsNothing(Session("UserName")) Or Session("UserName").ToString() = "" Then
            Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx")
        Else
            CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(Session("CustomerID"))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx")
    End Try


    'declares an instance of the database object allowing us to get the data from the table

    Dim tblCustomer As New DatabaseTable("Members.mdb", "select Email from tblCustomer", "#PN", "#PW")
    'declaring variables for loop
    Dim EmailNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Dim Email As String = txtEmail.Text
    Dim Counter As Integer
    'get the number of the emails
    EmailCount = tblCustomer.Count
    'loop thrue each item
    For Counter = 0 To EmailCount - 1
        'adds number to counter, if found message that subscribed
        If Email = tblCustomer.RecordNumber(Counter).Item("EMail") Then
            EmailNumber = EmailNumber + 1
            EmailOk = False
            'if did not find email will message that not subscribed
        ElseIf EmailNumber = 0 Then
            EmailOk = True

        End If
    Next

    Return EmailOk
End Function
```

>

And here is the changes which I tried and I thought it will work but no...

```
Dim tblCustomer As New DatabaseTable("Members.mdb", "select Email from tblCustomer where CustomerID <>" + CustomerId.ToString() + " ", "#PN", "#PW")
```

> 

CustomerID.ToString() is a logged in customer id written in from the session thus curren customer ID
Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I did solve the issue! I took me some time and it isn't too professional but it does the job! 
I am storing user's Email in session upon logging in. I am still using the same code for checking the email if it is in database but I only run the check if customer changed the email in text box. So first I am checking if email in text box = session email and if not everything is fine as email stays the same and it is correct as was validated upon registration. And it it isn't the same I run the validation code as it is. It looks messy tho so If someone still has a better idea of how to do it please let me know. As you can see I had to write the same part of code twice as there are two possibilities that validation is ok but I can only run GetEmail() when customer did alter the email textbox.

```
lbltester.Text = Session("UserEmail")
If txtEmail.Text = lbltester.Text Then
Dim myCustomers As New clsCustomer
clsCustomer.Update(txtFirstName.Text.Trim(), txtLastName.Text.Trim(), txtHouseNumber.Text.Trim(), txtStreet.Text.Trim(), txtCity.Text.Trim(), txtCounty.Text.Trim(), txtCountry.Text.Trim(), TxtPostCode.Text.Trim(), txtPhone.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim(), CustomerId)
Dim popupScript As String = "alert('Profile Updated Sucessfully');"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", popupScript, True)
Else
Call GetEmail()
     If EmailOk = True Then
     Dim myCustomers As New clsCustomer
     clsCustomer.Update(txtFirstName.Text.Trim(), txtLastName.Text.Trim(), txtHouseNumber.Text.Trim(), txtStreet.Text.Trim(), txtCity.Text.Trim(), txtCounty.Text.Trim(), txtCountry.Text.Trim(), TxtPostCode.Text.Trim(), txtPhone.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim(), CustomerId)
     Session("UserName") = txtFirstName.Text.Trim() + " " + txtLastName.Text.Trim()
      Dim popupScript As String = "alert('Profile Updated Sucessfully');"
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", popupScript, True)

        Else

        Dim popupScript As String = "alert('Email already exist in database');"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", popupScript, True)
        txtEmail.Focus()
        End If
     End If
```